# How do I add assemblies in a Virtual sub-directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I have an ASP.Net main Application that runs numerous other applications in virtual sub-directories so I can maintain the context. The normal ASP.Net applications have an individual `web.config` on each sub-folder containing their assemblies.

One of the new applications is MVC so I created a routing engine so I can access it in the sub-directory. It worked fine but I can't have the application's specific assemblies on my Root `web.config` (the http module and the routing I can). I can't find a way to add its assemblies in a `web.config` in its own sub-directory just in the root.

Is there a way to add an assembly to a MVC application that's running on a virtual sub-directory besides adding it to the `web.config` of the main application?